# Creating a Plot of Two Functions with Different Colors

Tags: plotting

I'm creating a plot with two functions on it and I am trying to make each function a different color. I have tried

```
f[x_] = Sin[x]
g[x_] = Cos[x]

Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2*Pi, 
  2*Pi}], PlotStyle -> {{Black}, {Blue}}
```

as well as

```
f[x_] = Sin[x]
g[x_] = Cos[x]

Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2*Pi, 
  2*Pi}], PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black], Directive[Black]}
```

but I get this syntax error each time

```
Plot[{Sin[x],Cos[x]},{x,-2*Pi,2*Pi}],PlotStyle->{Directive[Black],\
Directive[Black]}" is incomplete; more input is needed.
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from. For this particular question, try: `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black], Directive[Blue]}]`

Comment: Also try with and without the `PlotStyle` to see the difference: `f[x_] := Sin[x];
g[x_] := Cos[x];
Plot[{f[x], g[x], f[x] g[x]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}
 (*,PlotStyle\[Rule]{Red,Green,Black}*)]`

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake with the brackets. The following works fine

```
f[x_] = Sin[x]
g[x_] = Cos[x]

Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Black}, {Blue}}]
```

> [image: plot]